# How to override enum's "name" property?

Tags: dart

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
enum Foo {
  a,
  b;

  String get name {
    switch (this) {
      case Foo.a: return 'A';
      case Foo.b: return 'B';
    }
  }
}

void main() {
  printEnum<Foo>(Foo.values);
}

void printEnum<T extends Enum>(List<T> list) {
  for (var e in list) {
    print(e.name);
  }
}
```

The `for` loop prints

```
a
b
```

But I wanted it to print

```
A
B
```

So, how do I override the `name` property in the enum?

---

##### Note:

Using `(e as Foo).name` will solve the issue, but I have many enums in my project, so I can't cast them like this.

Also, please don't post answers like, use `toUpperCase()`, etc, because I just provided a simple example, but in real world, things are quite different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot override the `name` getter "on `Enum`" because it's an extension getter, not an instance getter.
Overriding, aka. late binding, of instance members only apply to actual (virtual) instance members.

Extension members are statically resolved, so a call of `.name` either hits the extension member, or it doesn't, and it depends *entirely* on the static type of the receiver. If you have an `Enum e; ... e.name ...` then it will call the extension member, and there is absolutely no way to change that, or change what it does.

If you want to have a custom and overridable `name` getter, I'd introduce an interface like

```dart
abstract class NamedEnum implements Enum {
  String get name;
}
```

and then let all your enums implement `NamedEnum`.
Then you can do `(enumValue as NamedEnum).name` for any of your enums.
It won't interact with other `enum` types' extension `name` getter.

Comment: Yes, I knew the `name` is defined on the extension and not in the `Enum abstract class, what I meant was how to provide my own name implementation to all my enums, and this is the proper answer, thanks :)

Comment: When I try `abstract class NamedEnum extends Enum`, I get `Error: The class 'Enum' can't be extended outside of its library because it's an interface class.`

Comment: The `Enum` class was made `interface` in Dart 3.0. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just override `toString()` in your enum, and call e.g. `Foo.a.toString()` to get the text representation `'A'` of the enum value:

```
enum Foo {
  a('A'),
  b('B');

  final String _text;

  const Foo(this._text);

  @override
  String toString() => _text;
}
```

Comment: I am not using enhanced enum.

Answer (score 1):

Casting `e` as `dynamic` works, as long as you ensure that the `name` property exists on the enum you are printing. Ex:

```dart
void printEnum<T extends Enum>(List<T> list) {
  for (var e in list) {
    print((e as dynamic).name);
  }
}
```

Comment: `for (dynamic e in list)` will work too! Thanks